# Trigger a function after a PHP variable value is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The intention is edit an invioce based on the invoice_id value received from the selection of a particular invoice from the invoice list table. Since this is an edit form, the invoice related details should be pre-loaded from the database.

The code looks as follows:

```
$invoice_id= base64_decode($_REQUEST['invoice_id']);
require_once '../model/invoice.php';
$obj=new Invoice();
$val=mysql_fetch_assoc($obj->getInvoiceDetailsForEdit($invoice_id));
```

The HTML of the hidden input text field is:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="inv_no" id="inv_no" value="<?php echo $invoice_id ?>"/>
```

The Script that is to be triggered inorder to get the preselected category is:-

```
<script>
        function getSelectedCategory(inv_no){
            if(inv_no!==""){
               var request = $.ajax({
                   url: "../controller/invoice.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: {inv_no:inv_no,action:'get_selected_category'},  
                   dataType: "json"
               });
               request.done(function(json_return){ 
                   $('#category').val(json_return['category_code']);
               });  
               request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                   return false;
               });
           }
        }
</script>
```

The Controller code:-

```
function getSelectedCategory(){
    $inv=$_POST['inv_no'];
    require_once '../model/invoice.php';
    $obj=new Invoice();
    $result=mysql_fetch_assoc($obj->getAllInvoiceDetailsForViewing($inv));
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
}
```

Everything is working perfectly except the fact that I don't know what to do to run the script after the php variable $invoice_id is being loaded since the text field cannot accept events as it is a hidden field..

I had changed the code as similar to the below one and found it is working:

```
<input type="text" name="inv_no" id="inv_no" value="<?php echo $invoice_id ?> onblur="getSelectedCategory(this.value)"/>
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful!!

Comment: So, your problem is Javascript, yes?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi Yep..Since I getting the intended output but the script should run without onblur or any event..I have tried document ready of jquery as well but no use its not working..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
function getSelectedCategory(inv_no){

window.onload = function(){
if(inv_no!==""){
               var request = $.ajax({
                   url: "../controller/invoice.php",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: {inv_no:inv_no,action:'get_selected_category'},  
                   dataType: "json"
               });
               request.done(function(json_return){ 
                   $('#category').val(json_return['category_code']);
               });  
               request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                   return false;
               });
           }
        }

}


}
```

I have added `window.onload` event to your JS function to make sure every element is loaded.

Comment: No its not working..Even the intended output now doesn't come.